# swift alamofire show viewcontroller after remote data has loaded

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, alamofire

I wonder how I can show a VC after the remote data has loaded. I am not using a tableView but a normal VC.

My code look like this:
`viewDidLoad`:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadItemData(id)
 }


func loadItemData(aId: Int) {
        Service.getItem(aId) { (JSON) -> () in

            self.iData = JSON

            self.configureData(self.iData)

        }
    }

func configureData(iData: JSON) {

        if let type = iData["item_type"].int {
            if let == 1 {
               someButton.hidden = true
            }

        }

        if let title = iData["item_title"].string {
        titleLabel.text = title
        }

}
```

What happens is that my VC first loads with the button visible and with my text label containing "dummy text" from storyboard, then when the data has loaded the button will hide and the text label will change.

So my question now is how I can hide my VC or show some loading indicator until the data has loaded.

Also worth saying this is the 2nd view. My apps start with a tableView and when you click on a cell you end up in this VC. So I could also load the data when the cell gets clicked then pass it to this VC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the activity indicator is better, here's how to do it

First make sure you add `Activity Indicator` in your VC

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myActivityIndicator.startAnimating()

        loadItemData(id)  
}


func loadItemData(aId: Int) {
        Service.getItem(aId) { (JSON) -> () in

        self.iData = JSON

        self.configureData(self.iData)
        self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

Rather than try to hide the VC (try to load the data and pass it), it will makes the apps feel not responsive, because you have to wait the data loaded and then the VC will show.